# php image type blob wont show

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to show the blop images i have in my mysql database. But all i get is a whitebox with no picture in it.

PHP code:

```
<?php 
require_once "include/config.php"; 
session_start();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM docenten";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows > 0){
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
      echo "<dt><strong>Foto:</strong></dt><dd>" . 
     '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.
      base64_encode($row['foto']).
      '" width="290" height="290">' . "</dd>";

    }
}else{
      echo "0 result";

     }
 ?>
```

But when the code runs all i get is this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjofs.jpg

Anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use addslashes before  insert

```
$img = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['images']['tmp_name']));
$query = "INSERT INTO tableName (id,image) VALUES('','$image')";
```